# How do I scrap all movie title, date and reviews on the website below? https://www.nollywoodreinvented.com/list-of-all-reviews

Tags: python, web-scraping, video, screen-scraping, review

I have tried with the code below and what the code does is to bring the first page and does not load completely the reviews for the movies. I am interested in getting all the movie titles, movie dates, and reviews.

```
enter code here


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.nollywoodreinvented.com/list-of-all-reviews'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0',



req = requests.get(url,  headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
movie_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='article-panel')
title=[] 




for div in movie_div:
    images= div.find_all('div', class_='article-image-wrapper')
    for image in images:
        image = image.find_all('div', class_='article-image')
        for img in image:
            title.append(img.a.img['title'])
date =[] 
for div in movie_div:
    date.append(div.find('div', class_='authorship type-date').text.strip())
info =[] 
for div in movie_div:
    info.append(div.find('div', class_='excerpt-text').text.strip())

import pandas as pd 
movie = pd.DataFrame({'title':title, 'date':date, 'info':info}, index=None)
movie.head()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a backend api which serves up the HTML you are scraping you can see it in action if you open your browsers Developer Tools - Network tab - fetch/Xhr and click the on a the 2nd or 3rd page link, we can recreate the POST request with python like the below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

pages = 3
results_per_page = 500 #max 500 I think

headers =   {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.nollywoodreinvented.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'

output = []
for page in range(1,pages+1):
    payload = {
        'action':'itajax-sort',
        'view':'grid',
        'loop':'main loop',
        'location':'',
        'thumbnail':'1',
        'rating':'1',
        'meta':'1',
        'award':'1',
        'badge':'1',
        'authorship':'1',
        'icon':'1',
        'excerpt':'1',
        'sorter':'recent',
        'columns':'4',
        'layout':'full',
        'numarticles':str(results_per_page),
        'largefirst':'',
        'paginated':str(page),
        'currentquery[category__in][]':'2648',
        'currentquery[category__in][]':'2649'
        }

    resp = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=payload).json()
    print(f'Scraping page: {page} - results: {results_per_page}')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp['content'],'html.parser')

    for film in soup.find_all('div',class_='article-panel'):
        try:
            title = film.find('h3').text.strip()
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        date = datetime.strptime(film.find('span',class_='date').text.strip(),"%B %d, %Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        likes = film.find('span',class_='numcount').text.strip()
        if not likes:
            likes = 0
        full_stars = [1 for _ in film.find_all('span',class_='theme-icon-star-full')]
        half_stars = [0.5 for _ in film.find_all('span',class_='theme-icon-star-half')]
        stars = (sum(full_stars)+ sum(half_stars))/2.0

        item = {
            'title':title,
            'date':date,
            'likes':likes,
            'stars':stars
        }

        output.append(item)


df= pd.DataFrame(output)
df.to_csv('nollywood_data.csv',index=False)
print('Saved to nollywood_data.csv')
```

Comment: Oh! Great. Thanks for the help. However, this code did not scrap the reviews in the output. In the case of my earlier code, the review was scraped but no the full reviews